# Calling an event for control on an inactive tab results in an exception

Tags: wpf, user-controls, controls

There is a control that has animation DoubleAnimationUsingPath, the animation is triggered by the event RoutedEvent = "ui:CheckBoxProgressCircle.Check"

```
<EventTrigger RoutedEvent="ui:CheckBoxProgressCircle.Check">
    <EventTrigger.Actions>
        <BeginStoryboard>
            <Storyboard>

                <DoubleAnimationUsingPath Storyboard.TargetName="AnimatedTranslateTransform"
                                            Storyboard.TargetProperty="X"
                                            PathGeometry="{StaticResource CheckAnimationPath}"
                                            Source="X"
                                            Duration="0:0:.1" />

            </Storyboard>
        </BeginStoryboard>
    </EventTrigger.Actions>
</EventTrigger>
```

In the code, I register the event:

```
static CheckBoxProgressCircle()
{
    CheckEvent =
        EventManager.RegisterRoutedEvent("Check", RoutingStrategy.Tunnel, typeof(RoutedEventHandler), typeof(CheckBoxProgressCircle));
}

public event RoutedEventHandler Check
{
    add
    {
        AddHandler(CheckEvent, value);
    }
    remove
    {
        RemoveHandler(CheckEvent, value);
    }
}
```

Then I call the event:

```
var newEventArgs = new RoutedEventArgs(CheckEvent);
RaiseEvent(newEventArgs);
```

If the control is on a tab that is active, everything works without errors, if the control is on a tab that has never become active, I get an error:

> ''AnimatedTranslateTransform' name cannot be found in the name scope of 'System.Windows.Controls.ControlTemplate'.'

I think this is due to the fact that the control did not render, because was on an inactive tab and does not have AnimatedTranslateTransform, how I can force wpf to render this element before the tab will become active? Or if I'm wrong, what can I do about it?

Comment: ACtivate your tab before you fire the event

Comment: Hi, this is a bad option, because the user may not need this. At the same time, control can be activated from another tab and this will result in an exception. I want control to work regardless of whether it was already shown or not.

Comment: Why would you want to animate something if it is not shown ?

Comment: Animation is not necessary, but then I need to somehow determine that the button is not displayed.
Animation is invoked from the base class for this control

https://yadi.sk/i/s9Vub7vD3R3oGS

Comment: The solution turned out to be quite simple: you can call the ApplyTemplate () method; for this control.
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.applytemplate.aspx

Answer (score 0):

The solution turned out to be quite simple: you can call the ApplyTemplate () method; for this control.
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.applytemplate.aspx